# Powershell - MSI extractor script i made no longer working, need advice on what to do

Tags: windows, powershell

I made a question about actually making this back in Novermber, and it worked pretty well. I had people test on Windows 7 as well and it was fine. However today I wanted to use it again, and guess what? It doesnt work. It fails to extract with the script and I'm not sure why.

```
msiexec /a $FileBrowser.FileName /qb TARGETDIR=$($FolderBrowser.SelectedPath)
```

`$FolderBrowser.FileName` points to a new ComObject instance of `Wscript.shell`, this is for the file select dialog. `$FolderBrowser.SelectedPath` is similar but is for the output. when i run `msiexec` from the terminal itself, and use direct paths and not variables, it doesnt work either. When using `/i` it asks for admin (which is the whole reason I made this, to bypass that) and when using the syntax i have in the script, it just errors out, saying the package is invalid.

Here's the script if you want to look at it: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesIsWack/Simple-MSI-Extractor/main/MSI-extractor.ps1

Any help is appreciated,
James